# Not able to reduce extra space between image and paragraph

Tags: html, css

[image: Another Image][image]

I have designed an app and applied inline style, such image and text appear side by side. I see there is an extra space between image and text. I also see "Demo Analysis Application" is shown as "Demo Analysis" and in next line "Application". I want image and next to it "Demo Analysis Application".

I have shown what I tried below.I have marked what I don't want in the picture.

```html
<table class="mainTable" style="margin:auto;">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="1" style="height:65px;width:200px;padding:0px; padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:20px; border:0px; margin:0px;">
      <img src="images/test.jpg" alt="Logo" width="200px" height="100px">
    </td>

    <td colspan="1" style="height:65px;padding:0px; padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:20px; border:0px; margin:0px;">
      <p style="height:65px;width:200px;font-weight:bold;font-size:26px;">Demo Analysis Application</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please use placeholder.com to add an image and add any missing CSS

Comment: just remove the width attribute in your first td

Comment: Thank you, I also want " Demo Analysis Application" to be in same line

Answer (score 2):

```html
<table class="mainTable" style="margin:auto;">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="1" style="height:65px;width:auto;padding:0px; padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:20px; border:0px; margin:0px;">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/05/11/56/image-in-the-image-2204798_960_720.jpg" alt="ANSYS Logo" width="200px" height="100px">
    </td>

    <td colspan="1" style="height:65px;padding:0px; padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:20px; border:0px; margin:0px;">
      <p style="height:65px;width:200px;font-weight:bold;font-size:26px;">Demo Analysis Application</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please check this code.I think this is what you want.

Comment: Can you make "Demo Analysis Application" to appear in same line.

Comment: You mean demo in JSFiddle?

Comment: I got the text "Demo Analysis Application" to appear in the same line now, thanks

Comment: I still see a gap between image and text, you have manged to remove it in jsfiddle

Comment: @karansys which image you are using?.Can you please try my codes image src and then inform me if you still facing issue.

Comment: The image inside td, takes a fixed space, only after that text appears

Comment: okay @karansys please give me your image link .I will make code snippet with that image.

Comment: It is the same with any image it takes block space only after that text appears

Comment: this is the style for main div , this might answer, why image takes block space style="display:none; padding-left:60px; padding-right:60px; height:94%"

Comment: I changed my image and checked the code in JSfiddle too,there also I am not facing any white space issue. change your td tags width to auto .Maybe there is an issue of image,Text is properly setting right side of image but maybe due to tds fix width ,there have an issue.